# Pyspark Insert Values in Table

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a table with a lot of columns which looks like something like this:

```
A B C D E
1 3   6 7
```

The new data arrives with files and does not always contain all of the columns so it might look something like this

```
C D A
1 2 3
```

Since the table and the dataframe have a lot of columns what would be the best approach to insert new values i.e. map the values to table by column names dynamically since I cannot state all of the columns. The table is delta table in Databricks.I am quite new to Pyspark so I do not know if append will match the columns or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For example, I have a Delta table in Databricks like below:

[image]

And then I have tried the following approach using PySpark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col
new_file_path = "/FileStore/tables/dbfscsv.csv"
new_df = spark.read.csv(new_file_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
missing_columns = set(df.columns) - set(new_df.columns)
for col_name in missing_columns:
    new_df = new_df.withColumn(col_name, lit(None))
for col_name, col_type in df.dtypes:
    new_df = new_df.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast(col_type))
new_df = new_df.select(df.columns)
new_df.write.format('delta').mode('append').saveAsTable('delta_new01')
```

**Results:**

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   3   null    6   7
3   null    1   2   null
```

- In the above code, the `spark.read.csv` method is used to read the  **CSV**  file into a new DataFrame  **new_df**. The `header=True` indicates that the first row of the  **CSV**  file contains the column names, and `inferSchema=True` lets Spark infer the schema (data types) of the columns.
- Next, it calculates the set difference between the columns of an existing DataFrame (df) and the new DataFrame (new_df) to identify any missing columns in  **new_df**. For each missing column, it adds a new column with the same name to  **new_df**  and fills it with `None` values `cast` as integers.
- After ensuring  **new_df**  has the same columns as  **df**, it selects the columns from  **new_df**  that match the columns of  **df**  and overwrites  **new_df**  with this selection.
- Then, it writes the  **new_df**  DataFrame to a Delta Lake table  **delta1**, appending the data to the existing table if it already exists.

The above approach dynamically adds missing columns to make sure that the schema of the DataFrame aligns with the table schema.